# Copy list of files with tar command. Bash

Tags: tar

I have the directory A/a A/b where both  a and b are files.

When I run these commands I get the outputs.

> -> tar --include A  -v -cf A.tar A

```
a A
a A/a
a A/b
```

> -> tar --include A/a -v -cf A.tar A

I don`t understand in the 2nd evocation why file A/a is not archived. I believe I do not understand how include works.

I am trying to give tar a list and have it create an archive with the contents. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: This turned out to be a silly question. All I needed was ```tar -v -cf A/a``` though I am still curious what the use if the --include flag does in a way I can understand.

Comment: I think `--include` is best used in conjunction with `--exclude` to override part of a previous exclusion (e.g. `--exclude A --include A/a`).